# .htaccess- [Options -Indexes] does not work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I placed my .htaccess file within the directory www/html/... with all my sub-folders/files within that directory. My server running Apache.

This is the only content of .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

However I am still able to access sub-folders. Why would this be?

If you need any further information please ask.

Comment: What do you mean by `still able to access sub-folders` ? Can you see a listing of folders' content ?

Comment: Do you have any other htaccess in subfolders ? Are you sure your htaccess is executed (apache config) ?

Comment: @JustinIurman How can I check if it is executed?

Comment: Search for this line `<Directory />` in apache config (`httpd.conf`) and check if `AllowOverride` is set to `All` instead of `None`

Comment: @JustinIurman I am editing apache2.conf. (There is no httpd.conf) I set it to 'All' but nothing changed so I changed it back to 'None'.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after setting `All` and saving ?

Comment: @JustinIurman I set it the option to all and saved it, then restarted it. Nothing happened as I am still able to access directories from url-typing within my browser. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To make `.htaccess` file with `Options -Indexes` working you need to add/edit `AllowOverride All` in that part of .conf file where is `<Directory>` for that folder.